# Resulution of graphics for mobile games

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, graphics

Does it matter, how high the resultion of my graphics are (the picture of my player is 1500 x 2000 px) or are there any problems, that the game couldn't work very well or smooth or something like that? (Unity, 2D Game)

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the target device, as well as the scale of your game. I wouldn't think that it would cause issues, but it really depends on how many large images you have rendered at the same time. You can also always change the max size in the sprite settings if it becomes a problem.

Also keep in mind that if your player is small it really doesn't need to be that large, so I would just go ahead and decrease the max size in the sprite settings if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are asking about texture size.

modern hardware can handle resolution such as 1500 x 2000 very easily and I would not worry about rendering speed.

However, texture loading (affects both CPU & GPU) may become issue if you have large textures (or large number of textures). if you have 1000 textures of 1500 x 2000, it will become hard to load the texture without affecting user experience.